# How to map an array of maps from firestore in react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to navigate an array of orders stored in each "User". I am able to query and find ones that have orders but I'm not able to display them. I keep getting an error "Cannot read property 'map' of null". Where am I going wrong?
The image below shows how all the orders are stored in "order"

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { firestore } from "../../../FireBase/FireBase";

const OrdersAdmin = (props) => {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      const doc = await firestore.collection("Users");
      const snapshot = await doc.where("orders", "!=", []).get();
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
        return <h1>No Orders</h1>;
      }
      var ans = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data().orders);
        setOrder(doc.data().orders)
      });
    };

    fetchOrder();
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div className="adminOrders">
      <h1>orders</h1>
      {console.log(order)}
      
      {order.map((orderItem) => (
              <div className="singleOrder" key={orderItem.id}>
                  <p>{orderItem}</p>
              </div>
          ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default OrdersAdmin;
```

Comment: It the order of opperation. The component first returns a view and only then executes the `useEffect`. Hence at first you have `null` as value. Make a check before `.map` to see if `order` has a value  `order && order.map((orderItem) => ...` or when declaring default value make it an empty array `const [order, setOrder] = useState([])`. In addition, if using `useState([])`, when you setting the value via `setOrder` you need to past in a new array rather then modified one as the state wont update other vise.

Comment: Thank you this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the initial value of `order` is `null`. `null` does not have `Array.prototype.map`, therefore you get the error. Try updating your render to use conditional rendering to only attempt `Array.prototype.map` when `order` is truthy and an `Array`:

```
{order && order.length > 0 && order.map((orderItem) => (
  <div className="singleOrder" key={orderItem.id}>
     <p>{orderItem}</p>
  </div>
))}
```

Otherwise you can use a better default value of an empty array for `order` which would have `Array.prototype.map` available to execute:

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);
```

Hopefully that helps!